# Wakeup SharePoint with PowerShell as Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, scheduled-tasks, keep-alive, wakeup

I have this integration to SharePoint which only works when the SharePoint site has been visited. I've made a PowerShell script to open Internet Explorer, pass credentials and close IE again. Works great when I'm logged on to the server. BUT when I set up the job as a schedule it doesn't work. Found out that the task does not have access to the UI, and therefore does not access the site as if the user is logged on. I've tried a script running thru files and sites to see if that wakes the site, but no luck. I need to get pass the "Working on it..." screen on the site before the integration works. Need to do this every morning
[Working on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iim0.png)

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$ie = Start-Process -file iexplore -arg 'http://[websiteurl]' -PassThru
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
Sleep 1
$wshell.AppActivate('Windows Security')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('[Domain]\[service_account]')
$wshell.SendKeys('{tab}')
$wshell.SendKeys('[service_account_password]')
$wshell.SendKeys('{enter}')
sleep 25
$ie.Kill()
```

Any ideas on how to wake my sharepoint automatic? How to visit the page on the UI on a scheduled task?

Comment: What error does your script throw when the SharePoint site is "asleep"?

Comment: If the SharePoint server hasn't been visited I get this error:

PDF.js v1.9.426 (build: 2558a58d)
Unexpected server response (0) while retrieving PDF "https://[sharepointurl]/api/fileserver/servicereport/36876115".

Comment: When creating the scheduled task, which user account is shown under 'when running the task, use the following account'?

Comment: The task is running as the same user as my script ([Domain]\[service_account]). The user has "log on as batch job" rights, and rights to open the SharePoint site. The task is set to "Run whether the user is logged on or not". The UI would show if the task setting was "Run only when the user is logged on", but the server is not idle with users logged on. Therefore this is the only avalible setting.